# Hyperlink inside dynamic userControl

Tags: asp.net, html, user-controls, hyperlink

I have a userControl being dynamically added to my form, anywhere from 1 to 20 times.
The control contains hyperlink field (visible) and a reference field (invisible).  The problem is that the hyperlink is not passing the value of the reference field as linked page parameter.

The userControl coding looks like this:

```
    <asp:Hyperlink ID="childLink" Enabled="true" DataNavigateUrlFields="aSeq" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Header.aspx?aSeq={0}" NavigateUrl="~/Header.aspx"
 runat="server><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cName") %> </asp:HyperLink>
```

So, the hyperlink should open the Header page, passing the value of the "aSeq" field which looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="aSeq"  Enabled="true" DataNavigateUrlFields="aSeq" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Header.aspx?aSeq={0}" NavigateUrl="~/Header.aspx" 
                runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.genePK") %></asp:HyperLink>
```

It does go to the page load for Header.aspx page, but the `Request.QueryString["aSeq"]` is always NULL.  On the Page_Load I have a short block of code:

```
string aRequest = Request.QueryString["aSeq"];
        if (aRequest==null)
        {
            PopulateHeader("GKEAAHDI");
        }
        else
        {
            PopulateHeader(aRequest);
        }
```

I can only surmise it has not gotten the value of the field tagged "aSeq".  I used a hyperlink because a textbox will not allow a code block for the databinder.

What have I done!?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN " The value of the field specified by the DataTextField property is passed as a query string to a Web page specified in the format string."  So you would need to add DataTextField="aSeq" in your asp:hyperlink declaration.

Not tested, just researched.